# WP_Query arguments relation shows AND instead of OR

Tags: wp-query

In `wp_postmeta` I have a meta_key which stores colon separated strings such as "CA:Georgia:NY".

So for meta_key='state' there can be several entries like:

For post 1 = "CA:Georgia:NY'

For post 2 = "CA"

For post 3 = "Georgia:CT'

For post 4 = "WA:CA"

I want to make a query to find out all the posts for which the meta_key contains 'CA' or 'Georgia'.

I building the WP_Query arguments dynamically.

```
$statelist = array();
$args = array(
    'post_type'     => 'post',
    'meta_query'    => array(
    'relation'      => 'OR')
);

if($_GET['state'] != NULL)
{
    $state_arr = explode( ',', $_GET['state']);
    for($i=0; $i<count($state_arr); $i++)
    {
        //tried also with relation = OR for first entry
        $current_arr = array('relation' => 'OR' , 
        array(
            'key' => 'state',
            'value' => $state_arr[$i],
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ));
        array_push($statelist, $current_arr);
    }
}

if(count($statelist) >= 1)
    array_push($args['meta_query'], $statelist);
```

But I'm always getting the Query as follows:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID
FROM wp_posts
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id)
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1 ON (wp_posts.ID = mt1.post_id)
WHERE 1=1
  AND ((((wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'state'
          AND CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) LIKE '%Georgia%')) **
        AND** ((mt1.meta_key = 'state'
                AND CAST(mt1.meta_value AS CHAR) LIKE '%CA%'))))
  AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post'
  AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
       OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private')
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0,
                                       50
```

As a result this query is picking up only
post 1 = "CA:Georgia:NY'

Though I want all the posts where `meta_key='state'` has either 'CA' or 'Georgia'. Despite explicitly creating the array with relation `OR` it is switching to default `AND`.

What should be the ideal way to construct the `Query` arguments?
It would be great if experts throw some light.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument structure is not correct. It should be like

```
[meta_query] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [key] => state
                [value] => a
                [compare] => LIKE
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [key] => state
                [value] => b
                [compare] => LIKE
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [key] => state
                [value] => c
                [compare] => LIKE
            )

        [relation] => OR
    )
```

But it is like

```
[meta_query] => Array
        (
            [relation] => OR
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [relation] => OR
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [key] => state
                                    [value] => a
                                    [compare] => LIKE
                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [relation] => OR
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [key] => state
                                    [value] => b
                                    [compare] => LIKE
                                )

                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [relation] => OR
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [key] => state
                                    [value] => c
                                    [compare] => LIKE
                                )

                        )

                )

        )
```

Change your code in this way to match recommended structure

```
$statelist = array();
$args = array(
    'post_type'     => 'post',
    'meta_query'    => array(
    'relation'      => 'OR')
);

if($_GET['state'] != NULL)
{
    $state_arr = explode( ',', $_GET['state']);
    for($i=0; $i<count($state_arr); $i++)
    {
        //tried also with relation = OR for first entry
        $current_arr = array(
            'key' => 'state',
            'value' => $state_arr[$i],
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        );
        array_push($statelist, $current_arr);
    }
}

if(count($statelist) >= 1) {
    $statelist['relation'] = 'OR';
    $args['meta_query'] = $statelist;
}
```

Ref: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query

Comment: Fantastic!!! Thank you Sumit! Worked like a charm...